# Trying to understand word boundries

Tags: java, regex

I am learning about regular expressions and more specifically word boundries. I have a piece of code that I feel should return at least one match but it however doesn't.

What is wrong with the code I used

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean matches;
    String [] various = {"Men of honour", "X Men", "Children of men", "Company men are great"}; 

    for(int i = 0; i < various.length; i++)
    {
        matches = Pattern.matches("\\bMen", various[i]);

        System.out.println("Does the string match the pattern? " + matches);
    }



}
```

out put is as follow

```
Does the string match the pattern? false
Does the string match the pattern? false
Does the string match the pattern? false
Does the string match the pattern? false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.matches()`, you're asking the regex engine if your pattern matches the whole input string. However, you want to know if your pattern can be found somewhere inside the input string.

Use :

```
Pattern.compile("\\bMen").matcher(various[i]).find()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not because of the word boundaries. It's because the `.matches()` method requires the *entire* string to match. It can't extract submatches.

You want something like

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\bMen", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
for(int i = 0; i < various.length; i++)
{
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(various[i]);
    matches = regexMatcher.find();
    System.out.println("Does the string match the pattern? " + matches);
}
```